# PHP password protected form help. 1 output works, multiples do not

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to figure out why one form works but another one of mine does not. I'm trying to create a form that lets the user choose various bundles, enter a password, and then have the ability to download said files if it's correct. I'm able to do this with one file like so

```
<?php
 // Get the password
      $pw = md5($_POST['password']);

 // Compare against the stored password
      $valid_pw = md5("example");

      if($pw != $valid_pw){
           echo "Error! You do not have access to this file";
      }else{
           header("Location:files\bundle1.pdf");
      }
?>
```

However, I cannot get this to work. When I make a selection, enter the password and hit submit, I see a blank screen and the URL is of the PHP file. Here is the code:

```
<?php
 // Get the password
        $pw = md5($_POST['password']);                    
        $bundle1 = ($_POST['1']);
        $bundle2 = ($_POST['2']);
        $bundle3 = ($_POST['3']);
        $bundle4 = ($_POST['4']);

 // Compare against the stored password
      $valid_pw = md5("example");

      if($pw != $valid_pw){
           echo "Error! You do not have access to this file";
      }else{

$bundle1 = 'unchecked';
$bundle2 = 'unchecked';
$bundle3 = 'unchecked';
$bundle4 = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
     $selected_radio = $_POST['bundle'];

     if ($selected_radio == '1') {
            $bundle1 = 'checked';
            header("Location:files\bundle1.zip");
            exit();
      }else if ($selected_radio == '2') {
            $bundle2 = 'checked';
            header("Location:files\bundle2.zip");
            exit(); //added exits so program wouldn't continue to run after selection -k
      }
      else if ($selected_radio == '3') {
            $bundle3 = 'checked';
            header("Location:files\bundle3.zip");
            exit();
      }
      else if ($selected_radio == '4') {
            $bundle4 = 'checked';
            header("Location:files\bundle4.zip");
            exit();
      }
    }
 }
?>
```

The main difference (besides the else if statements) is that the working file is a .PDF and the nonworking ones are .zip. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You probably have a parse error somewhere, and perhaps error reporting is turned off.

Comment: [MD5 is not a secure way to hash your passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function). You might as well be storing them in plain text. Switch to [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which is considered secure

Comment: use header("Location:files\\bundle1.zip"); or header("Location:files/bundle1.zip"); use forwars slash or double backslash for escape and actual slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In double quotes php uses \ as escape sequence so instead use \ or / 
use 
`header("Location:files\\bundle1.zip");` or `header("Location:files/bundle1.zip");` 
use forwars slash or double backslash for escape and actual slash

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are wrong:

```
        header("Location:files\bundle1.zip");
                              ^---
```

HTTP uses `/` for path separators in URLs, no backslashes.  Since `\b` has no special meaning in a PHP `"`-quoted string, unlike `\n`, `\r` etc... it'll simply be ignored, and you're sending

```
Location:filesbundle1.zip
```

to the client.